# How to remove the least frequent element from a Counter in Python the fastest way?

Tags: python, data-structures

I'd like to implement a Counter which drops the least frequent element when the counter's size going beyond some threshold. For that I need to remove the least frequent element.

What is the fastest way to do that in Python?

I know `counter.most_common()[-1]`, but it creates a whole list and seems slow when done extensively? Is there a better command (or maybe a different data structure)?

Comment: You could have a min heap that associates values with their frequency. Then check the top of the min-heap and remove that element from the DS storing the values.

Comment: The problem with `counter.most_common()[-1]` also is that [items with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)

Answer (score 1):

You may implement `least_common` by borrowing implementation of `most_common` and performing necessary changes.

Refer to [`collections` source in Py2.7](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py):

```
def most_common(self, n=None):
    '''List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
    common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.

    >>> Counter('abcdeabcdabcaba').most_common(3)
    [('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3)]

    '''
    # Emulate Bag.sortedByCount from Smalltalk
    if n is None:
        return sorted(self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return _heapq.nlargest(n, self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1))
```

To change it in order to retrieve least common we need just a few adjustments.

```
import collections
from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter
import heapq as _heapq


class MyCounter(collections.Counter):
    def least_common(self, n=None):
        if n is None:
            return sorted(self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=False)  # was: reverse=True
        return _heapq.nsmallest(n, self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1))  # was _heapq.nlargest
```

Tests:

```
c = MyCounter("abbcccddddeeeee")
assert c.most_common() == c.least_common()[::-1]
assert c.most_common()[-1:] == c.least_common(1)
```

Comment: This will still create a full list with all items, so it has the same downside as `most_common()`. And actually no real benefit since accessing the last element of a list has the same time complexity as accessing the first.

Comment: @poke you may pass an argument `n` to most_common (least_common) to avoid creating huge list. It's used right there in tests, `c.least_common(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your stated goal is to remove items in the counter below a threshold, just reverse the counter (so the values becomes a list of keys with that value) and then remove the keys in the counter below the threshold.

Example:

```
>>> c=Counter("aaaabccadddefeghizkdxxx")
>>> c
Counter({'a': 5, 'd': 4, 'x': 3, 'c': 2, 'e': 2, 'b': 1, 'g': 1, 'f': 1, 'i': 1, 'h': 1, 'k': 1, 'z': 1})

counts={}
for k, v in c.items():
    counts.setdefault(v, []).append(k)

tol=2   
for k, v in counts.items():
    if k<=tol:
        c=c-Counter({}.fromkeys(v, k))
>>> c
Counter({'a': 5, 'd': 4, 'x': 3})
```

In this example, all counts less than or equal to 2 are removed.

Or, just recreate the counter with a comparison to your threshold value:

```
>>> c
Counter({'a': 5, 'd': 4, 'x': 3, 'c': 2, 'e': 2, 'b': 1, 'g': 1, 'f': 1, 'i': 1, 'h': 1, 'k': 1, 'z': 1})
>>> Counter({k:v for k,v in c.items() if v>tol})
Counter({'a': 5, 'd': 4, 'x': 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the least common value, then the most efficient way to handle this is to simply get the minimum value from the counter (dictionary).

Since you can only say whether a value is the lowest, you actually need to look at all items, so a time complexity of O(n) is really the lowest we can get. However, we do not need to have a linear space complexity, as we only need to remember the lowest value, and not all of them. So a solution that works like `most_common()` in reverse is too much for us.

In this case, we can simply use `min()` with a custom key function here:

```
>>> c = Counter('foobarbazbar')
>>> c
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'o': 2, 'r': 2, 'f': 1, 'z': 1})

>>> k = min(c, key=lambda x: c[x])
>>> del c[k]
>>> c
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'o': 2, 'r': 2, 'z': 1})
```

Of course, since dictionaries are unordered, you do not get any influence on which of the lowest values is removed that way in case there are multiple with the same lowest occurrence.